# Find all reaccurances of text inbetween two strings

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to find a text between `$something` and `$something_else` and ditch it out in an array.
I would think you need `preg_match` to do this but I have been trying alot and still have no idea.

This should work no matter what `$something` and `$something_else` is.

Comment: Please provide more details with examples what you want. That really helps to answer.

Comment: Also post attempted solutions with some description why/where they failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read the documentation of [**`preg_match`**](http://www.php.net/function.preg-match) and [**`preg_match_all`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php).

Here's a simple example that will match whatever content inside (double quotes)..

```
<?php
preg_match_all('~"(.*?)"~',
    'Hey there "I will be matched", because "I am inside the double quotes"',
    $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

print_r(($out[0]));
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => "I will be matched"
    [1] => "I am inside the double quotes"
)
```

Comment: I have tried something alike but whenever I change it to preg_match_all("$something(.*?)$something_else", $text, $ret); print_r( $ret ); it doesn't work. I want to be able to get the text inbetween __REGARDLESS__ of what the variables inputted are

Comment: @CakeSneer, Unless we see your code, it's hard to help.

Comment: @CakeSneer If `$someting` and `$someting_else` contain any regex special characters, they will be processed as such. You need to surround them with `\Q` and `\E` : `preg_match_all("\Q$something\E(.*?)\Q$something_else\E", $text, $ret);`.

Comment: @RémiSvahn, `Delimiter` right ?

Comment: @Shankar Damodaran, yeah, I was a little fast. Should be `preg_match_all("~\Q$something\E(.*?)\Q$something_else\E~", $text, $ret);`

Comment: @Rémi Svahn Will this grab the string between it regardless of what the string contains?

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if i am wrong. We can use explode one string into a array. Use pre_match_all for the another string with each word of the array . In this way, it will work with any string.